# How to detect many outliers by test from non-linear parameter in R

Tags: r, outliers, nonlinear-functions

I need to detect many outliers from non-linear parameter by test.  I used some methods like [outliers](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/outliers/outliers.pdf) Package, but in many cases the conventional methods do not meet the test assumptions.

Here a small example of a large amount of data that have,

Two vectors, "x" and "y":

```
x <- c(50.012, 2.0255, 1.4552, 1.4186, 1.1831, 0.9782, -0.4291, -7.0972, -37.1922, -41.3537, -41.817, -45.3403, -53.7224, -74.8426, -184.1533, -208.8941, -248.6897, -344.1792, -347.6185, -354.0921, -523.5459, -573.9206, -694.4206, -694.6722, -1039.5303, -1303.6301, -1640.6454, -1645.6708)
y <- c(0.0000, 0.0002, 0.0000, 0.0004, 0.0019, 0.0002, 0.0043, 0.0448, 0.0513, 0.1482, 0.0112, 0.0451, 0.0000, 0.1492, 0.1583, 0.3885, 0.3000, 0.2033, 0.3656, 0.2368, 0.4934, 0.2180, 0.5161, 0.4920, 0.5229, 0.5394, 1.3575, 1.4175)
```

when I plot "x" and "y" by:

```
plot(x, y)
```

It is clear that there exist two outliers:

```
x[27:28]
y[27:28]
```

I have lots of data like this, and I need good nls estimations by non-linear regressions like this:

```
sigmoid <- function(x, x0, a, b) {
  a*exp(-exp(-(x-x0)/b))
}

nlsfit <-nls2(y ~ sigmoid(x, x0, a, b), start = data.frame(x0 = c(0, -5), a = c(0, 1), b= c(-0.01, -5)))
```

Through a test, How I can detect and remove many outliers?, regardless of the length of "x" and "y".

Comment: I can easily fit a `nls` curve through those points and have `27:28` not be outliers. They're not that outrageous with a straight line of best fit either.

Comment: Thelatemail Yes you're right, but it is impossible to have values such as and I know that these points are wrong and I need the best fit parameter and I need an mathematical excuse to delete it.  For example If I not change and change the outliers the resulting parameters are:

x0= -5727.32  and  -196.71
a = 53.87  and  0.50
b= -3116.35  and  -203.54

And those are very significant changes in the parameters